# Can symmetric positive definite matrices be orthogonal with respect to the Frobenius product

Tags: matrices

Can symmetric positive definite matrices be orthogonal with respect to the Frobenius product?

This does not seem to be the special class for diagonal symmetric positive definite matrices.

Here, the Frobenius product $(A,B)$ of matrices of size $n \times n$ is

$(A,B) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij}$

Comment: @BenGrossmann OP specifies positive definite matrices

Comment: @angryavian Thanks, missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $A^{1/2}$ denote the (symmetric) positive definite square root of $A$. We have
$$
\langle A,B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}([A^{1/2}]^2 B) = \operatorname{tr}(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})
$$
The matrix $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ is symmetric and positive definite. It follows that this matrix has a non-zero trace.

Comment: How would one show that $A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}$ is positive definite?

Comment: @a For any invertible matrix $P$ and (symmetric) positive definite $B$, $P^T B P$ is also positive definite

Comment: Ah I'm getting rusty. Thanks!